# WiFi much slower on Ubuntu 14.04 than Windows 10 using RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI

Tags: drivers, wireless, connection, ralink

I recently installed Ubuntu MATE 14.04 and I can no longer connect to the WiFi from down the hall from where my router is. I moved my desktop closer to the router (now a few feet away) and the connection is still very slow. Here is some info:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 6
   bus info: pci@0000:04:06.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:24:1d:39:f1:9f
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt61pci driverversion=3.16.0-77-generic firmware=0.8 ip=10.0.0.10 latency=32 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
   resources: irq:20 memory:fdef0000-fdef7fff


me@computer:~$ modinfo rt61pci
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-77-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless    /rt2x00/rt61pci.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2661.bin
firmware:       rt2561s.bin
firmware:       rt2561.bin
description:    Ralink RT61 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     4BFC565D4BD3484DB7DBB7B
alias:          pci:v00001814d00000401sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00000302sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001814d00000301sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6,crc-itu-t
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-77-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:               4A:94:AF:F5:EF:F7:B5:39:90:6B:3F:2A:9D:0C:CA:00:DA:C4:CB:B0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)
```

Comment: Please edit question to add results for `iwconfig`

Comment: Also: `dmesg | grep rt2`